# How can I get this code to include more than just the first occurrence in the loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to take an input and output it with alternating upper and lower case.

Example, if I type in `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` the O's in fox and dog aren't output the way i'd like. Same thing happens with double vowels too like "good" or "beets" etc. Is there a way to make the code include occurrences after the first? Also I haven't learned enumerate or any modules like that, I was trying to make it work with what I have learned so far. Thank you.

```
text = input('Enter a sentence: ')

def sponge(t):
    new = ''
    for i in t:
        if int(t.index(i)) % 2 == 0:
            new += i.lower()
        else:
            new += i.upper()
    return new

print(sponge(text))
```

Comment: Add expected output to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `t.index(i)` function returns the index of the first occurrence of `i`. With what you know, just add a counter variable:

```
text = input('Enter a sentence: ')

def sponge(t):
    new = ''
    counter = 0
    for i in t:
        if counter % 2 == 0:
            new += i.lower()
        else:
            new += i.upper()
        counter += 1
    return new

print(sponge(text))
```

Comment: Aha! I wouldn't have thought of that, that worked exactly how I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
text = input('Enter a sentence: ')

def sponge(t):
    new = ''
    for i in range(len(t)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new += t[i].lower()
        else:
            new += t[i].upper()
    return new

print(sponge(text))
```

I guess the problem in your code is that when you use `.index` to find the index of the character it always returns the first one it finds.